# Modifying specific elements in sublist without loop

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of list which I am trying to modify in a particular way. The list of lists is organized similar to a matrix, but each element is a numerical vector. My goal is to update only a small number of these vectors based on their position. For example updating the 4th element in some of the sublist. Here is an example of what I am looking for. For simplicity sake I left a lot of the elements missing.

```
 foo <- list(list(NA, NA, NA, c(2)),
        list(NA, NA, NA, c(1, 5, 9)),
        list(NA, NA, NA, c(1, 5, 9)),
        list(NA, NA, NA, c(7)),
        list(NA, NA, NA, c(5, 8, 9)),
        list(NA, NA, NA, c(1, 8, 9)))
```

Suppose I want to remove 9 from the 4th elements of sublist 3-6, corresponding to elements `foo[[4]][[4]]`, `foo[[5]][[4]]` and `foo[[6]][[4]]` in a systematic way?

I have been trying to go about this somehow using lapply doing something like this.

```
lapply(foo, "[[", 4)[4:6] %>% lapply(function(x) x[!(x %in% 9)])
```

Which works fine, but I haven't figured out a good way to put these updated vectors back into the list so that the result is what is below. I know I could do it with loops, but I am hoping to avoid them as this process will be repeated many times and I figure that there is a better way to do this.

```
> foo
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] NA

[[1]][[2]]
[1] NA

[[1]][[3]]
[1] NA

[[1]][[4]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]][[2]]
[1] NA

[[2]][[3]]
[1] NA

[[2]][[4]]
[1] 1 5 9


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] NA

[[3]][[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]][[3]]
[1] NA

[[3]][[4]]
[1] 1 5 9


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] NA

[[4]][[2]]
[1] NA

[[4]][[3]]
[1] NA

[[4]][[4]]
[1] 7


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] NA

[[5]][[2]]
[1] NA

[[5]][[3]]
[1] NA

[[5]][[4]]
[1] 5 8


[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[1] NA

[[6]][[2]]
[1] NA

[[6]][[3]]
[1] NA

[[6]][[4]]
[1] 1 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
foo[4:6] <- lapply(foo[4:6], function(x) c(x[1:3], list(x[[4]][!(x[[4]] %in% 9)])))


foo[4:6]
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] NA

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] NA

#[[1]][[3]]
#[1] NA

#[[1]][[4]]
#[1] 7

#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] NA

#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] NA

#[[2]][[3]]
#[1] NA

#[[2]][[4]]
#[1] 5 8
#......
```

We change values only at `4:6` lists, `c`ombine `1:3` sublists as it is and filter the values from the 4th list.

Comment: Ahh, nice. Yea that will work for what I need. Seems so obvious now that I am seeing it. Thanks.